# CKEditor HTML CODE TROUBLE SHOOTING

Tags: drupal, button, paypal, ckeditor

My issue is I have a drupal site and I am trying to create a Make Payment page. I was able to create the page but the issue I ran into is when I got the code for the button from PayPal and inserted it into the CKEditor. The CKEditor works when I put it in there but it wont publish.

Any tips would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to set the Input Format for that text box to "Full HTML". Otherwise a lot of the HTML tags will be stripped out when it is displayed.